# Changing the code font size in WebStorm IDE

Tags: ide, webstorm

I can't seem to find a way to change the code font size in WebStorm. I change the font size in options and it changes the menu and toolbar font size but not the actual code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `Font`, **Size**:

Before you can change this setting you must click "Save As..." and save the scheme under a custom name.

[image: Font size]

Comment: There is no such an option in version 10.0.4

Comment: @DamjanPavlica there is, [refer to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html).

Comment: As of **Webstorm 2021.2.1** I found it under `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Font` | **Size:**

Answer (score 57):

If you came here because you already found that screen, but the text box was locked...

This is because you cannot modify the current theme.

Click "Save As..." to save a copy of your current theme, now you should be able to edit whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you!  While I am generally addicted to Jetbrain products (admittedly, ReSharper convert, so...), sometimes I wish some things were more intuitive (hard to verbalize, but I never find myself scratching my head too long when trying to accomplish something in Sublime (ctrl+'+'/scroll up))...  This was exactly the guidance I needed!

Comment: thanks for providing this hint - exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks! There should be something to suggest this in the app as I couldn't figure out why I couldn't change the font!

Comment: Omg, the user experience is horrible... at least let the user KNOW why he/she cannot modify something. ugh. This is one of the things that sublime text, for example, solves VERY gracefully, by having a user settings file in which other package settings are being overwritten. So your UX doesn't get horrible.. :/

Answer (score 51):

There is also an option to enable mouse wheel zooming, like in browsers:

**File > Settings > Editor > Change font size with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel**.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are a **new WebStorm 10.0.4** user,

**File > Settings > Editor > General > *Change font size with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel*.**
[image]

Comment: There is no "general" under settings... it's not under code / syntax templates either (I'm on the latest webstorm)

Comment: @Kokodoko refer the screenshot :)

Comment: I just discovered that zooming works by pinching the touch pad on my laptop. Still don't know where to find it in settings, but at least I can zoom :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer that discusses how to dynamically change the font size via the mouse wheel is partially correct, but leaves out a crucial step:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Editor
4. General (this is the crucial step missing from the previous answer)
5. Set the "Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+M

The previous answer was missing the crucial step 4, which, when omitted, leaves you wondering where the magic checkbox control is located.

Comment: There is no "general" option under settings?