# Increase / Decrease code font size keyboard shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, rubymine, webstorm

I know how to change the setting : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129039/390330

But I want a more live solution like I get with the mouse: ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>*** shortcut. Except I need it to be a keyboard shortcut (e.g in browsers there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>). Is there such a keystroke / or can one be set

Comment: Really liking the tags on this question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Currently only <kbd>Ctrl+Mouse Wheel</kbd>

Corresponding ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84884

---

**UPDATE:** It has been implemented now (2 months later after writing this answer):

1. `Settings / Preferences | Keymap`
2. Type `font` in that screen search box
3. Assign custom shortcuts to `Increase` and `Decrease` actions

[image]

Comment: It's been added to IntelliJ 13! You can add a key map to Increase and Decrease Font Size.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following .. verified in Android Studio 2.0

1. Go to Preferences
2. Go to Keymap
3. In the search field, type `font`
4. There you can double click on Increase and Decrease, and "add" a custom key binding.

I used

Decrease: <kbd>ctrl -</kbd>

Increase: <kbd>ctrl +</kbd>